# Making child wider than its parent without width

Tags: css

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    content...
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make #child as wide as the content is? Making it wider than #parent, which has a fixed width, if needed.

(in my case content is an unknown text string that I don't want to line break)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set [`display:inline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) and [`white-space:nowrap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-white-space) on your `#child`, which will give you the results you're desiring. The container will only be as wide as the content within, and will exceed the width of the parent if necessary.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ebuxup/edit#html,live

Answer (score 4):

Try with this CSS to avoid line break at all `#child { white-space: nowrap; }`.

Infos here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: What's the problem with that site? I just linked the first Google result that explain that property...

Comment: @sandeep & Truth- I suppose you are both grammer nazis aswell. http://aspektas.com/blog/w3fools-a-foolish-attack-on-w3schoolscom/